# Outlook showing the wrong Meeting type (Lync instead of Skype)

Tags: exchange, outlook, skype

I'm currently experiencing an issue after setting up and integrating a Skype for Business 2015 test environment with Exchange 2019.

I have a windows client with Office 2013 located in the LAN, and on creating a new appointment I can only see "Lync Meeting" instead of "Skype Meeting".

Clicking on the "Lync Meeting" button results in the error appearing in the attached image, even if the Skype For Business Basic client is running and the user is signed in.
[Lync Meeting Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTxjx.png)

In order to integrate Skype for Business 2015 with Exchange 2019 I followed this guide (part 1 only): [Integrating Skype For Business 2015 with Exchange guide](http://lyncdude.com/2015/10/06/the-complete-skype-for-business-exchange-2016-integration-guide-part-i/index.html)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, if you don’t install any office update, it would show “Lync” instead of “Skype” with Office 2013.

And according your error, check you have signed in Lync client, and make sure your Outlook default profile account SMTP address (user@domain.com) is same as the Lync login address (user@domain.com).

Comment: I tried updating, it seems my office 2013 is SP1 on a specific version (15.0.4569.1506) and I tried updating it and no matter what I did it didn't update...
I've installed Office 2016 instead, and now everything is working.

If you have any ideas how to solve the office 2013 not updating - I'd be glad

Comment: I think you may try to install the SFB client update. First install the April 14 2015 update, it would change the UI from Lync 2013 to SFB 2015, then install other newer version.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2998606/how-to-obtain-the-latest-update-for-skype-for-business-2015-lync-2013

Comment: I'll test this.